# Replacing current canvas in onDraw

Tags: android, canvas, surfaceview, ondraw

I got a surfaceView which in the onDraw function I try to change the current canvas by creating a new canvasBitMap:

```
Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) canvas.getWidth(), (int) canvas.getHeight(), conf); 
canvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
Temp temp = new Temp(canvas);
```

I then try to print the canvas ID to see if temp.getCanvas is the same as canvas:

```
Log.d("Debug", "Canvas: " + canvas);
Log.d("Debug", "Temp Canvas: " + Temp.getCanvas());
```

The result from the printout is:

```
Canvas: android.view.GLES20RecordingCanvas@34cbdc63 
Temp Canvas: android.graphics.Canvas@276f78f4
```

Question is simple, Why arent they the same?

br

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you created a new one.  The incoming canvas is a canvas that points to the screen (or more properly, to a buffer in the graphics card that will be drawn to the screen).  The one you created draws to a new in-memory bitmap that you created in your create bitmap function, and will draw to that bitmap, not the screen.

Comment: He only created one canvas... he did create a new "Temp" but who knows what that is.

Comment: He passed in that canvas to temp.  I think we can safely guess that getCanvas on an object that takes  a canvas as its parameter via Constructor and nothing else is going to return that canvas.  Notice he also says he's in onDraw of a SurfaceView, which is why the other canvas is an openGL recording canvas.

Comment: well I'm really confused then. He is printing out "canvas" and "temp.getCanvas()" which according to your comment, should be same instance, since as you said it was passed in the constructor and retrieved via the get method. ?